# Не работает полнотекстовый поиск с двумя параметрами

Tags: mysqli, запрос

Запрос типа

```
SELECT * FROM tb WHERE MATCH (title,content) AGAINST ('some words')
```

не работает ни с классом mysqli, ни с расширением stmt. Если в скобках указать только одно значение - либо title, либо content, то запрос успешно выполняется. Запрос с двумя параметрами также выполняется, если указать `IN BOOLEAN MODE`. Ответа на такое поведение я не нашел, на форумах ни у кого такой проблемы не возникает.

Comment: http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/Fulltext_Search.html

Comment: @rnddev, я это читал полдня. Поэтому и вопрос задал.